# Failing to connect remotely to MySQL after setting everything up correctly

Tags: php, mysql, database-connection

I have an issue getting to connect remotely to a MySQL database.

My current set-up is as follows: I have a windows 2008 Server at work, placed behind a router (fixed IP). The router has DMZ configured to the server, which works perfectly fine for everything else I have tested including web server, VPN, FTP, etc... The firewall of the Server is opened to the necessary services on the corresponding ports. I can telnet to all these ports decently.

The only thing that I cannot get to work is remotely connecting to a MySQL database. I have done all of the following:

- Forward port 3306 to the Server (through DMZ);
- Configure MySQL to bind to `0.0.0.0:3306` (it automatically does that when not supplying a `bind-address`);
- Configure a user account in MySQL with access from `localhost`;
- Configure the very same user account (same name, password, rights) with access from `'%'`;
- Open port 3306 in the Windows Server's firewall.

I am subsequently trying to execute a PHP script from a hosted web server (elsewhere on the internet):

```
<?php
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli(<host>, <username>, <password>);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
echo "Connected successfully";
?>
```

with `<host>`, `<username>` and `<password>` being the corresponding and correct credentials.

This script simply times out without reply and gives the expected error `Connection failed: Can't connect to MySQL server on '<host>' (110)`. I can also not telnet on port 3306. Connecting from `localhost` works fine.

I don't know what else I have forgotten or done wrong. What am I missing?

I need this connection in order to keep my 'backup system' centralized on the hosted web server. I could run my 'backup system' locally on the mysql host, but that makes it harder to manage it from the central point. Beside that, I'd like to get it to work to actually know what's going on. I hate not getting this kind of thing to work.

Thanks for anyone who has ideas on what could be wrong.

Kenneth

Comment: first ping the host from the machine you are running this code, then continue to telnet the port.

Comment: I could have mentioned that before, but pinging the host works from several locations. I cannot test this from the web server because I don't have the appropriate access rights.

Comment: I am also assuming you have allowed remote connection on your mysql server. here http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-enable-remote-access-to-mysql-database-server.html

Comment: Hello, Yes I have followed a similar procedure. `# skip-networking` is indeed quoted out and there is no `bind-address` (so to use the standard `0.0.0.0`). Binding `127.0.0.1` works only locally. Binding the server's internal IP `192.168.50.254` doesn't work. Same goes for the public IP address.

Comment: Is there something _else_ already running on 3306? Can you run a scan or test by binding different service to 3306?
Edit: or bind mysql to a port other than 3306

Comment: I hope are not also using `192.168.50.254` because it is private ip.

Comment: Also, enable verbose connection logging in the mysql server and see if it detects any connection attempt?

Edit: see here http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-logs.html

Comment: what does this give you `telnet192.168.50.254 3306`?

Comment: This is what i would check. Can you connect to the 'mysql server' from the 'internal network using its fixed 'internal ip address' with similar user credentials that an external user would use? If so then the issue is likely to be 'seeing the server externally'. Do you own the internet connection or if you have a 'service provider', do they block certain ports anyway? These are just thoughts.

Comment: Greetings, thanks for the help so far. telnetting from inside the network to with `telnet 192.168.50.254 3306` says 'connecting...' and eventually 'Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed'. Same applies when telnetting from outside the network. I cannot connect from the internal network either. The Internet Connection is owned by an ISP but all ports are ought to be opened. Ports 21, 80, 443 and all ports above 1024 that I tried with other services seem to be opened. Nothing else is running on port 3306, I've checked.

Comment: You may need to talk to 'support' and explain what you are trying to do, as in externally connecting to the database. Some ISP's forbid access to it, via external connections, period. You may decide to use a web server and a 'REST' interface to your external database.